# How to pass getopts argurements to a shell script using java

Tags: java, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I want to run a shell script using java using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. However, my shell script is using getopts so I need to use this command in terminal to run the script:

```
./script.sh -l 01 -n 02
```

So how can i execute this script with multiple args using java? I tried the bellow code but I does not work.

```
String[] args = {"script.sh", "-l 01", "-n 02"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

Comment: What error do you get? Is it a Java error or an error from the script being ran? If it's the script it's because it gets "-l 01" as one argument, while those should be passed as separate arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each argument is a separate `String`. Like,

```
String[] args = { "script.sh", "-l", "01", "-n", "02" };
```

Comment: You may also need `"./script.sh"` if the script is not in the $PATH.

Comment: Hi, Thanks it works when i add  "./script.sh" in also.